# How to add plus sign for positive number when using to_excel?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [2, 2, 2, -4, np.nan, np.nan, 4, -3, 2, -2, -6],
        'b': [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 6]
    }
)
```

I want to add a plus sign for positive numbers only for column `a` when exporting to Excel. For example 1 becomes +1. Note that I have `NaN` values as well. I want them to be empty cells in Excel similar to the default behavior of Pandas when dealing with `NaN` values in `to_excel.`

I have tried many solutions. This is one of them. But it didn't work in Excel.

```
df.style.format({'a': '{:+g}'}).to_excel(r'df.xlsx', sheet_name='xx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a callable:

```
(df.style.format({'a': lambda x: f'{x:+g}' if np.isfinite(x) else ''})
   .to_excel(r'/tmp/df.xlsx', sheet_name='xx', index=False)
)
```

*Alternative callable: `lambda x: '' if np.isnan(x) else f'{x:+g}'`*

Output (in jupyter):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. In your screenshot there are no plus signs.

Comment: @x_Amir_x Yes I just saw that, but I opened in LibreOffice, not Excel, there are + signs in the jupyter notebooks though. Please double check in Excel.

Comment: I does not show up in excel. I think the only way is to change to `str`. Do you agree?

Comment: Most likely yes

Answer (score 7):

You can set a classical `+0;-0;0` (as per the [Spec 18.8.31/a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/c6046ec6-f96d-4609-98e4-0dd549292955)), with [xlsxwriter](/questions/tagged/xlsxwriter), as the [num-format](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-num-format) :

```
idx = df.columns.get_loc("a")
fmt = {"num_format": "+0;-0;0"}

with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as wr:
    df.to_excel(wr, index=False)
    wr.sheets["Sheet1"].set_column(
        idx, idx, cell_format= wr.book.add_format(fmt)
    )
```

[image]